# only replace NA by another dataframe in large multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe(df1) with some NA values:

```
   ID X01 X02 X03 X04      ... X100
1 A01  NA  NA   4   2      ...   NA
2 A02   2  NA   2   2      ...    4
3 A03  NA   2  NA  NA      ...    4
4 A04   2   4   4  NA      ...   NA
5 A05  NA  NA   4   2      ...    2
6 A06   2  NA  NA   4      ...   NA
```

Then i have a df2 as below

```
   ID X01 X02 X03 X04      ... X100
1 A01   1  99   4   2      ...    1
2 A02   1  99   1   2      ...    4
3 A03  99   1  99   1      ...    4
4 A04   2   4   4  99      ...    1
5 A05  99   1   4   2      ...    2
6 A06   2  99   1   4      ...   99
```

I would like to replace the NAs in df1 with values in the same position by another dataframe(df2)
and keep value of df1 not NAs original.

The resulting df3 want be like this

```
   ID X01 X02 X03 X04      ... X100
1 A01   1  99   4   2      ...    1
2 A02   2  99   2   2      ...    4
3 A03  99   2  99   1      ...    4
4 A04   2   4   4  99      ...    1
5 A05  99   1   4   2      ...    2
6 A06   2  99   1   4      ...   99
```

And I tried this not worked.

```
df1 %>% dplyr::rows_update(df2, by = "ID)
```

Any help will be great Thanks!!

Comment: Try this: `df1[is.na(df1)] <- df2[is.na(df1)]`

Comment: @Sotos, Hi, thank you for help, In my df1 and df2 , rows are not on the same order(ID column). when I used this will fill wrong value of position,and my df1 and df2 are so large, not easy to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::coalesce`, e.g.

```
df1 <- mtcars
# create some NA entries
df1[1,] <- NA
df1[,1] <- NA

df2 <- mtcars

df <- dplyr::coalesce(df1, df2)
df
```